# How to reset password in IBM Portlet application using PUMA API

Tags: websphere-portal, spring-portlet-mvc

I have a below code to reset password which uses PUMA API of IBM Portal:
Below code checks whether user entered old passoword correct or not:

```
loginService.checkPassword(userName, oldpswd.toCharArray());
```

Below code update the new password:

```
ibmPumaUtility.updateUserPassword(userName,resetPasswordForm.getNewPassword());


PumaController pController = pumaHome.getController();
            PumaLocator locator = pumaHome.getLocator();
            String defaultRealm = "xyz";
            User user = locator.findUserByIdentifier("uid=" + username + ",cn=users,o=" + defaultRealm);
            HashMap<String, String> userAttrs = new HashMap<String, String>();
            userAttrs.put("password", updatedPassword);
            pController.setAttributes(user, userAttrs);
```

The issue is, when user again logs in with old password, he is able to log in but only for some time 5-10 mins and after that he is able to login with the new password.

Can someone please suggest me how to resolve this.

Comment: the issue should be caused by the WebSphere security component. It caches the security subject for some time. I thought I had a PMR for this behaviour, but do not recall if or if not. You could check if you can invalidate the entry within the WebSphere Subject cache as the user logs out.

Comment: @StefanSchmitt I am new to Webshpere Portal application. Could you please suggest what is and how to validate WebSphere Subject cache?

Comment: check Sascha's answer that should help

Answer (score 2):

the API call you use to validate if the "old password" is still okay:
loginService.checkPassword(userName, oldpswd.toCharArray());

Does in fact use a performance optimized validation on WAS level in default. This is matching to the most use-cases.
The "real login" won't let you in - that really checks the current password.
So if you open up a 2nd browser and try to login to portal at that time with "old password" you won't get a valid session.
(there is an exception for some LDAP servers as they still allow login with the old password for about 60min).

But if you require the API to return the correct value immediately there is a config option for this.
You switch the "basic login" to a "full login" by:
• Click WP AuthenticationService. Under Additional Properties select Custom Properties.

• Click New to create new custom properties.

• In the Name field, type authentication.basic.login.target

• In the Value field, type Portal_LTPA

• Click OK to confirm the changes.

• Save the configuration.

• Restart the server.

After this change the validation will leverage the complete Portal_LTPA login stack and return with an error if the "old password" is used.